# How to keep already chosen value in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have following [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-goodall-8fb19).

What I'm trying to do is, in the first step, select one of the elements, store it in my state, and in the last step, console.log all my data. Also, the user can go from the last step to the first and change what he chose before. But the problem is that I can't save what the user selects for the first time.

For example, if the user selects the second one, and then on the last step they go back, then the first one is displayed as selected. How can I fix this?

here is my code

App.js

```
     const [current, setCurrent] = useState(0);
      const [data, setData] = useState({
        firstName: "AAA",
        lastName: "BBB",
        age: 26
      });
      const steps = [
        {
       content: (
        <PackageChoose setCurrent={setCurrent} data={data} setData={setData} />
        ),
        id: 0
       },
       {
        content: <LastStep setCurrent={setCurrent} data={data} />,
        id: 1
       }
     ];
     return (
       <div className="App">
        <div>{steps[current].content}</div>
      </div>
     );
```

packageChoose (or first step)

```
   const PackageChoose = ({ setCurrent, data, setData }) => {
     const [selected, setSelected] = useState(1);
     const [packageType, setPackageType] = useState(data.package || "choice");
     return (
        <div>
          <div
            onClick={() => {
            setPackageType("choice");
            setData({ ...data, packageType: packageType });
          }}
         >
           <SelectCard
             id={1}
             selected={selected}
             onSelect={setSelected}
             text="text 1"
          />
        </div>
        <div
          onClick={() => {
            setPackageType("select");
           setData({ ...data, packageType: packageType });
          }}
        >
         <SelectCard
           id={2}
          selected={selected}
          onSelect={setSelected}
          text="text 2"
        />
        </div>
        <button onClick={() => setCurrent(1)}>Next</button>
      </div>
     );
   };
```

Last step

```
    const LastStep = ({ setCurrent, data }) => {
    return (
       <div>
         LastStep
         <button
           onClick={() => {
             setCurrent(0);
           }}
         >
           Previous
         </button>
         <button onClick={() => console.log("data===>", data)}> submit </button>
       </div>
     );
    };
```

Selected Card reusable component

```
   const SelectCard = ({ id, selected, onSelect, text }) => {
     const myClassName =
        id === selected
          ? Styles.selectCardWrapperActives
          : Styles.selectCardWrapper;

      return (
        <div className={classNames(myClassName)} onClick={() => onSelect(id)}>
          <div> {text} </div>
        </div>
      );
    };
```

Please help me to fix this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can move the `selected` state in `PackageChoose` to `App` level.

1. In `App.js` define the selected state and pass as props.

```
export default function App() {
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState(1);
  ...
  ...

        <PackageChoose
          ...
          ...
          selected={selected}
          setSelected={setSelected}
        />
}
```

2. In `PackageChoose` use the props passed above and remove the local selected state.

```
const PackageChoose = ({ setCurrent, data, setData, setSelected, selected }) => {
```

[image: Edit hopeful-violet-zsv35]

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the `packageType` inside onClick handler. Since `setState` calls are batched and enqueued inside event handler and state updates [may be asynchronous](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous). You can't access the `packageType` state immediately after setting it.

**PackageChoose.js**

**Card 1**

```
onClick={() => setData({ ...data, packageType: "choice" })}
```

**Card 2**

```
onClick={() => setData({ ...data, packageType: "select" })}
```

set the `packageType` directly on `data`.